# Google Map tiles in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, google-maps

How I can add Google Map tiles in GeoServer?

like that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea3DaNAbOfE

Answer (score 1):

No, GeoServer can handle cascading tiles that are provided using a standard method WMTS. Google maps doesn't support that standard despite Google being members of the OGC.

It would also probably (IANAL) breach Google's ToS to cascade their tiles through GeoServer.

Comment: thanks for reply ian, How make google map as cascading tiles in GeoServer?

Comment: You would need to rewrite Google's tile serving API or add support to GeoTools but I don't think it would be legal to do this.